# Let $ a_ {n} $ a sequence such that $ a_ {n +1} = 2 ^ {a_ {n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could someone help me through this problem?

> Let $ a_ {n} $ a sequence such that $ a_ {n +1} = 2 ^ {a_ {n}} $, $ a_ {1} = 1$ show that 
>   $a_ {n}$ diverge to $+\infty$

Comment: Show that for instance $a_i\geq 2^{i-1}$, since the powers of two diverge, you must have that the sequence diverges.

Comment: Have you written the terms of the sequence out explicitly?

Comment: As @David is suggesting, you have that
$a_1=1$
$a_2=2$
$a_3=4$
$a_4=16$

Comment: I suppose that the succession goes to infinity with some terms that I found

Comment: Since every term is $\ge 1$, it diverges...

Comment: And what criteria I use to mean that diverges to +∞

Comment: @Emil, this is a sequence, not a sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $a_n$ makes the tetration $a_n =  \begin{cases} \underbrace{2^{2^{\cdot^{\cdot^{2}}}}}_{n-1}, & \mbox{if }  a > 1  \\ 1,  & \mbox{if } a = 1. \end{cases} = {^{n}2}$.

Euler proved that infinite tetrations in the form

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {^{n}x} = x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{x}}}}$$

only converges for $e^{−e} ≤ x ≤ e^{1/e}$.
Now, $2 > e^{1/e} \approx 1.44$, thus

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \infty$$